# Unable to set gopath

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have got go lang installed version 1.6.1/i386.  Using UBUNTU 16.04.

Whenever am trying to download gomobile tool using

`go get golang.org/x/mobile/cmd/gomobile`  it gives an error saying

> cannot download: gopath not set

I have tried looking for solutions online but nothing seems to work, maybe am doing it wrong.

Comment: I rolled back your edit. No need to ask us to be kind. Also, this not being a forum but a Q&A archive, we want a single question per question.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work with windows instead. If anyone else looking for how to set gopath on windows:- http://www.wadewegner.com/2014/12/easy-go-programming-setup-for-windows/